# How to make C look into a file and find a certain string?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, do-while, modulo

I have a file that contains information on employees in the following format:

> Name: Belal Kassem
>   Service: Security
>   Date of Birth: 1995
>   Salary: 500
>
> Name: Abdallah Yasser
>   Service: Marketing
>   Date of Birth: 1954
>   Salary: 500
>
> Name: Hend Elkarmouty
>   Service: Dentist
>   Date of Birth: 1990
>   Salary: 800

I would like my program to search for an employee's name, which is indicated by the user, and then return `true` or `false` (found/not-found).

However, right now, my program only asks for the number of employees I want to remove and their names.

```
int NumToDelete;
printf("How much employees do you want to remove?\n");
scanf(" %d", &NumToDelete);
fgetc(stdin);
char Name[NumToDelete][25];
for(int i = 0; i < NumToDelete; i++)
{
    printf("Name: ");
    fgets(Name[i], 25, stdin);
    char BarLoc, NameFinder[25];
    int line = 0;
    FILE *fremove = fopen("Employees.txt", "r");
    do
    {

        if((line % 5) == 0)
        {
            fseek(fremove, 6, SEEK_CUR);
            fgets(NameFinder, 25, fremove);
            if(NameFinder == Name[i])
            {                             //This is not the official code.
                printf("%s", NameFinder); //Just to check if it is working or not.
            }                             //Here it is suppose to be the deleting code. 
        }
        BarLoc = getc(fremove);
        if(BarLoc == '\n')
        {
            line++;
        }
    }while(BarLoc != EOF);
```

I would also like to print out, using the NameFinder variable, all employees which were deleted.

Comment: May not be your only problem, but you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings

Comment: `if(NameFinder == Name[i])` compares pointers, not string contents.

Comment: If this is a practical problem, I'd recommend putting your data into [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/index.html) and then doing the rest with SQL.

Comment: @chux may you suggest a alternative? Should I do something like this: `if(NameFinder == &Name[i])`?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes it worked. my code is now `if(strcmp(NameFinder, Name[i]) == 0)`

Comment: You should work toward reading all data from your file in a single pass and separating the employees into either an array of struct, or a linked-list of struct or something similar. That way all employee data is held in memory and you can easily search, add, remove employees as needed and then write the updated data a single time on exit.

Answer (score 3):

Use `strcmp` to compare the strings, like this:

```
if(!strcmp(NameFinder, Name[i]))
{                             //This is not the official code.
   printf("%s", NameFinder); //Just to check if it is working or not.
}
```